# bash: convert files within subfolders and output to another folder

Tags: bash

My files are organized as G:\Songs\Songs - FLAC%album artist%%album%\ . I have a bash script to trim the silence from the start and end of the tracks and output them as mp3. If I run the script from G:\Songs\Songs - FLAC, it will not convert the tracks in the subfolders. Is there any parameter that would convert the files within the subfolders? Also, I would like to output the trimmed songs to G:\Songs\Trimmed. Is this possible?

The script:

```
        #!/bin/bash

        for file in *.flac
        do
        ffmpeg -i "$file" -af silenceremove=start_periods=1:start_duration=1:start_threshold=-65dB:detection=peak,aformat=dblp,areverse,silenceremove=start_periods=1:start_duration=1:start_threshold=-65dB:detection=peak,aformat=dblp,areverse -q:a 5 "${file%.*}.mp3"
        done;
```

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`globstar`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/The-Shopt-Builtin.html).

your match will include arbitrary depths of subdirectories, so your command logic and parameter parsing for output filenames won't even need to change.

```
$: shopt -s globstar
$: printf "%s\n" **/*.flac
foo/bar.flac
foo/there.flac
here.flac
```

Parameter parsing for the new names is pretty easy -

```
for file in **/*.flac; do
  echo "$file -> ${file%.*}.mp3"
done
foo/bar.flac -> foo/bar.mp3
foo/there.flac -> foo/there.mp3
here.flac -> here.mp3
```

So for your script, assuming your args are right,

```
shopt -s globstar
for file in **/*.flac do
  bare="${file##*/}"
  ffmpeg -i "$file" -af silenceremove=start_periods=1:start_duration=1:start_threshold=-65dB:detection=peak,aformat=dblp,areverse,silenceremove=start_periods=1:start_duration=1:start_threshold=-65dB:detection=peak,aformat=dblp,areverse -q:a 5 "/new/location/${bare%.*}.mp3"
done
```

Make sure you include the `shopt s globstar` before the loop, and change where I said `/new/location/` to wherever you actually want your trimmed files.

Comment: so will this output to a separate folder outside the one containing the subfolders?

Comment: You can make it do whatever you need. As written, it will make the new files beside the old ones, in whatever folder they now reside. If you need something different, it's just a matter of adjusting the logic. Run it with my echo instead of your actual `ffmpeg` command to see the source and target filenames.

Comment: so ive got my script now

`#!/bin/bash

for file in **/*.flac
do
ffmpeg -i "$file" -af silenceremove=start_periods=1:start_duration=1:start_threshold=-65dB:detection=peak,aformat=dblp,areverse,silenceremove=start_periods=1:start_duration=1:start_threshold=-65dB:detection=peak,aformat=dblp,areverse -q:a 5 "${file%.*}.mp3"
done;`

but i am not sure how to output to another directory. any pointers?

Comment: @Tactic54, see [What to do When someone answers my question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers#:~:text=Choose%20one%20answer%20that%20you,the%20answer%2C%20at%20any%20time)